# How to use JS Excel API in my web application using data from my server

Tags: javascript, office-js, office-addins, exceljs, office-js-helpers

Is it possible to run js excel api in my web application using data from my server. I want to use this api as a replacement of html data table.

Need a step by step guide if possible and what are the T&C for any commercial use.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with one of these to libraries:

1. **ExcelJs**: https://npmjs.com/package/exceljs / https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs
2. **Xlsx-import**: https://npmjs.com/package/xlsx-import / https://github.com/siemienik/xlsx-import

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about the [Office JavaScript API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/understanding-the-javascript-api-for-office), it has to run in the context of a JavaScript engine embedded in an Office app (Excel, in your case) and it can interact with the workbook that is open in Excel, not with a workbook on a server. To get data from workbooks on a server, you can use [Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph). (For workbooks stored on SharePoint on premises, you can use [Excel Services REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/excel-services-rest-api-overview).